# Global git file location linux

Tags: git, centos

I am using a Centos 
I am looking for my global git config file
Could anyone let me know where would I find the file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Typing `man git config` has a section called FILES that lists the locations of all the system files.  The global Git config file is in `~/.gitconfig`, but there's also a "system" config file, that's usually in `/etc/gitconfig`.

Comment: So it does (on Linux, on OS X it shows the git man page and then the config man page)

Comment: On CentOS `man git config` shows me the `git` man page, no `git config`s

Answer (score 44):

you can also find/edit those configuration files running the commands:

```
git config --global -e
git config --system -e
git config --local -e
```

Comment: Assuming it's not the case that the whole reason you need to know the file location is that your `core.editor` value is broken... :)

Comment: yeah, still doesn't tell you where it is.

Comment: maybe you want to know where it is to copy paste into a file. maybe to back it up. maybe just to know the file path as you're doing a mass migration and see if it'll match your regex or not. etc. beiong able to edit =/= knowing where it is.

Comment: @ahnbizcad when you run one of those commands it opens the file inside an editor. The editor usually shows you where the file is located or give you the option to save the contents in another file. But maybe not all editors show you where the file is located.